# how to avoid these polygons going through polygons in animation

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, weight-painting

the skin is coming through the armor. I thought of just deleting all the faces inside so that they don't come through but the weight paint is inside. I'm finding it difficult to individually weight paint because this is low poly and there isn't a smooth transition. I'm considering of redoing the model and deleting unnecessary face (ones that are inside) before I parent with automatic weights. Is there a way to fix this or do I have to redo my model? If I do have to redo it, what are some things I need to keep in mind when modeling?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe you could add bones to control the belt

Comment: @moonboots would it be better if I separated the armor and the character mesh and also give them separate rigs? how would they link?

Comment: I don't think it will make things easier if there are several armatures, no. Just create additional bones that are parented to the belly bone, parent the belt to these bones only, and move the bones the way you want so that faces don't cross. The problem is that you're using an armature like metarig and if you don't know how it works it will make the things more difficult

Comment: @moonboots Ok ill will look more into this thank you ;>